# как реализовать выделение и вставку текста в определенное место textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

здравствуйте, как можно реализовать такую систему которая используется в том же SO, когда я выделаю текст в этой textarea, и нажимаю на к примеру B (жирность) этот текст выделяется этим типом

ну или код жирности добавляется в то место куда происходит клик мышкой, как это делается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно реализовать вот так:

```js
function wrapText(elementID, openTag, closeTag) {
  var textArea = $('#' + elementID);
  var len = textArea.val().length;
  var start = textArea[0].selectionStart;
  var end = textArea[0].selectionEnd;
  var selectedText = textArea.val().substring(start, end);
  var replacement = openTag + selectedText + closeTag;
  textArea.val(textArea.val().substring(0, start) + replacement + textArea.val().substring(end, len));
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#select-my-block').on('click', function() {
    wrapText("my-block", "[#bold]", "[/bold]");
  });
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="my-block">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum corporis fugiat magnam ab, soluta commodi accusantium at doloremque eum libero delectus debitis cumque facilis vero aliquid distinctio praesentium officiis? Aliquid.
</textarea>
<button id="select-my-block">Выделить жирным</button>
```

Comment: спасибо, я вот решил вернутся и переспросить у вас, можно ли как-то изменить скрипт чтобы во время первой вставки символа в точку куда была кликнута мышь, после этого второй, третий и так далее клик так же делал вставку в это место? просто дело в том что если нажать больше 1 раза подряд, текст вставляется только в самое начало